# How is the (global) $L^2$ norm defined for a discrete vector field?

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces

The (global) $L^2$ norm of a discrete scalar field S is easy. Say $S = [a, b, c]$ then
$$\lVert S \rVert = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$$

But how is the (global) $L^2$ norm defined for a 2D vector field V?
Say $V = [(a_x, b_y), (b_x, b_y), (c_x, c_y)]$. I have seen several defintions go by, e.g.:

*Definition 1*: As the sum of the local $L^2$ norms:
$$\lVert V \rVert = \lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert + \lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert + \lVert \mathbf{c} \rVert = \sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y^2} + \sqrt{b_x^2 + b_y^2} + \sqrt{c_x^2 + c_y^2}.$$
*Definition 2*: As the Frobenius norm (i.e. concatenate x-components and y-components to one vector and compute $L^2$ norm of that new vector):
$$\lVert V \rVert = \lVert [a_x, a_y, b_x, b_y, c_x, c_y] \rVert = \sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y^2 + b_x^2 + b_y^2 + c_x^2 + c_y^2}.$$
*Definition 3*: As the $L^2$ norm of the local $L^2$ norms. This leads to the same results as the second definition:
\begin{align*}
\lVert V \rVert = \lVert \lVert V_i \rVert \rVert &= \lVert \sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y^2} + \sqrt{b_x^2 + b_y^2} + \sqrt{c_x^2 + c_y^2} \rVert\\
                                                  &= \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y^2}\right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{b_x^2 + b_y^2}\right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{c_x^2 + c_y^2}\right)^2}\\
                                                  &= \sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y^2 + b_x^2 + b_y^2 + c_x^2 + c_y^2}.
\end{align*}
*Definition 4*: As the sum of the $L^2$ norm of the x-components and the $L^2$ norm of the y-components:
$$\lVert V \rVert = \lVert V_x \rVert + \lVert V_y \rVert = \sqrt{a_x^2 + b_x^2 + c_x^2 \vphantom{a_y^2}} + \sqrt{a_y^2 + b_y^2 + c_y^2}.$$
I saw a few more definitions but I think my point is clear.

Is there some (un)written agreement what is the right or common definition?

My specific problem: I have a discrete field containing 2D error vectors, and I want to compute the global $L^2$ norm of this field.

Comment: Which norm you use depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I wanted to know if one of the definitions is more common than others. And if that is not the case, are there definitions that yield more intuitive values than others for common usage?